# how rescue ruby exception, but not failure in code block

Tags: ruby, exception

I want to catch the PuppetError::Error exception so it's not fatal, but a PuppetError::ExecError should be fatal.

My problem seems to be that the rescue clause is catching the PuppetError::Error then elevating it to ExecError status, so it isn't caught by the calling code.  I need to limit the rescue clause to one line, the Open3.. line.  But how?

```
module PuppetCert
  def self.remove(instance_hostname)
    begin
      Open3::popen3("puppet cert clean #{instance_hostname}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
        if wait_thr.value.success?
          puts "success"
        else
          raise PuppetError::Error
          return
        end
      end
    rescue
      raise PuppetError::ExecError
    end
  end
end

instances.each do |i|
  begin
    PuppetCert.remove(i)
  rescue PuppetError::Error
    logger.error("PuppetCert.remove failed. Not fatal")
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: To clarify, both PuppetError type are custom types I have created (not shown here) as a way to identify different sorts of failure. PuppetError::Error is for when the system call to the puppet binary fails; PuppetError:ExecError is for when Open3::popen3 fails because it can't find the puppet binary.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. You have a method definition and a piece of code that calls it. For each part, which error class do you want to rescue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two `rescue` clauses, one to catch `PuppetError::Error` and raise it again, then on the other catch everything else:

```
module PuppetCert
  def self.remove(instance_hostname)
    begin
      Open3::popen3("puppet cert clean #{instance_hostname}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
        if wait_thr.value.success?
          puts "success"
        else
          raise PuppetError::Error
          return
        end
      end
    rescue PuppetError::Error => error
      raise error
    rescue
      raise PuppetError::ExecError
    end
  end
end
```

The first `rescue` clause (the order matters, so it must come first) rescues `PuppetError::Error` and simply raises it again, that is, it only *intercepts* it before getting to the more general `rescue`, so it won't get promoted. Every other exception will be rescued by the second `rescue` clause and promoted as `PuppetError::ExecError`.

Comment: Ah that's great ta. I'm trying to rig a test now but that looks good. Thanks.